# .bat to search for directory with certain name and set into a copy path

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to search for a folder (c:\test) in a certain directory that has the word "current" in it. And then i would like to copy from a folder inside it (c:\test\current\first).

Any help would be much appreciated. I have done my research but so far I have only managed to do xcopy, but not the first 2. Sorry I'm relatively new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the structure, but seems you want to do:

from Batch file:

```
For /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /S /B /AD "N:\8\Installation Release" ^| findstr /i "web" ^| findstr /i "current"') do echo %%i
```

From Cmdline (Console):

```
For /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /S /B /AD "N:\8\Installation Release" ^| findstr /i "web" ^| findstr /i "current"') do echo %i
```

So as per your last comment, this is more or less what you would need to perform the xcopy:

```
For /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /S /B /AD "N:\8\Installation Release" ^| findstr /i "web" ^| findstr /i "current"') do (
xcopy "%%i"* /D /C /Q /R /Y /I /S "D:\Abc" & goto :eof
)
```

Comment: I have tried the script but it says incorrect syntax. Kindly advise.

Comment: I tested it and it works 100%. which one did you try in the script?

Comment: Hey Gerhard,

For /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /S /B /AD N:\8\Installation Release\ ^| findstr "current" ^| findstr "web" ') do 
c:\windows\system32\xcopy "%%i"\* /D /C /Q /R /Y /I /S "D:\Abc"

The exact directory is N:\8\Installation Release\Current 8.18.210\Web but the 'current' will change over time, hence I needed the 'findstr' function. Kindly advise where am I doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Gerhard,

It works now. However, it does not copy exactly what is inside the folder. There is supposed to be 23 folders and 12 files. But my copied location now has 50 folders and 16 files. It seems that it copied some of the internal folders/files out. Kindly advise.. Thank you very much.

Comment: I found out that the for loop lists every folder/directory inside N:\8\Installation Release\Current 8.18.210\Web. However I just need the "N:\8\Installation Release\Current 8.18.210\Web" directory. How do I break out of the loop after first iteration?

Comment: Have did so but it ran without copying anything. And no errors as well.

Comment: Sorry. Thought it was another thread. Removing it wont work. You need `/s` you would need to limit it to that string only as any subdir will also contain those search items.

Comment: The newest script somehow copies 2 folders inside of 'Current' folder. 
One is 'Web' which I intend to copy from, another one which I'm not intending to copy from.
Both folders were incomplete after they are copied.